# C# Windows app, clear textbox on focus

Tags: c#, textbox, focus

I'm very new to C# and I'm trying to make a simple GUI hangman game to help me learn. I am using a textbox to both output errors (The letter was already entered. Try again) etc. and input the user's guess. However my problem comes in that whenever the user is given an error, they have to manually clear the textbox. What I'm looking for is a feature in most search boxes, google for example, that clears (in google's case, highlights) the text currently in the box.

I know it can be simply done using

```
textboxname.Clear();
```

but I'm not sure where it should go, I can place it under the code for a button without a problem but my instinct is to put it outside of the button's {} , however when I try this the text box isn't recognized and if statements can't be used.

I think I'm looking for:

```
if (TextBoxName.Focus)
    {
        TextBoxName.Clear();
    }
```

But I'm just not sure where to put it

Comment: I think you are looking for the TextBoxName's Enter event.

Comment: Like this? `private void Guess_Entry_Box_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: Yes, but make sure the event is wired up.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new. But how does one go about 'wiring up' an event

Comment: @user2874417 How did you create the control? In code, or by dragging and dropping the element onto your form?

Comment: I dragged the text box from the toolbox in visual studio. It's Ok now though I found it! By going into 'Form.Designer.cs' and adding the line `this.Guess_Entry_Box.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.Guess_Entry_Box_Enter);` below the other Guess Entry Box code

Comment: Next time, select the control on the form and click on the Lightning Bolt icon in the Properties window.  Those are your events for the control.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still getting used to visual studio, that will help massively in the future I'm sure.

Comment: It is best to avoid editing Form.Designer.cs. That file is generated by the Visual Studio designer and is not guaranteed to persist your changes. If you must add an event handler through code, add it in the Forms `Loaded` event or in the Forms constructor. Otherwise, double click on the control in the designer, or select the designer and double click on the event you want to have via the Properties pane.